# Django elasticsearch_dsl only 10 results getting returned

Tags: django, elasticsearch

currently my Django elasticsearch view only returns 10 results where I expect at least 15 results to be returned. After some searching on the web I figured out that size = 10

See more here:
[How to Get All Results from Elasticsearch in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729753/how-to-get-all-results-from-elasticsearch-in-python/53730061)

But I don't understand how my syntax has to look like, this is how i query for post objects:

```
 post = PostDocument.search().query("multi_match", query=qs, fields=["title", "content", "tag"]).to_queryset()
```

I also tried:

```
post = PostDocument.search(size=1000).query("multi_match", query=qs, fields=["title", "content", "tag"]).to_queryset()
```

But with no success. Can smb. tell me how to change the default size to a higher value than 10 using elasticsearch_dsl with Django.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Got this issue fixed like this:

```
post = PostDocument.search().extra(size=100).query("multi_match", query=qs, fields=["title", "content", "tag"]).to_queryset()
```